# Помогите исправить баги проекта

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю текстовый редактор. Вот 
[проект на GitHub](https://github.com/KonstantinShirmanov/QtEditorPublic.git)

там весь код. Ошибки неявные (все компилируется), но не работает смена шрифта и кнопка "сохранить". Помогите исправить баги, спасибо.

Добавляю код кнопки сохранить

```
void MainClass::slotSaveClicked(){
    QTextDocumentWriter writer;
    writer.setFormat("odf");
    writer.setFileName("output.odf");
    writer.write (MainTextEdit->document());
}
```

И слот QFontComboBox

```
void MainClass::setTextEditFont(){
    QFont font = FStyleList->currentFont();
    font.setPixelSize( FontsizeSpin -> value());

    if (ItalyStyle->isChanged()){
        font.setItalic(true);
    }
    else if (BoldStyle->isChecked()){
        font.setBold(true);
    }
    else if (UnderLineStyle->isChecked()){
        font.setUnderline(true);
    }

    MainTextEdit->setFont(font);
}
```

Comment: Ссылка не работает, 404. Да и я сомневаюсь, что кто-то станет заморачиваться...

Comment: Покажите код изменения шрифта и кнопки сохранить.

Comment: Сделал жеж ужеж ) Что там опять не работает?

Comment: Как у вас компилятор вот такие штуки пропускает `ItalyStyle->isChanged()`?

Comment: Не пропускает. Это старая версия проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения шрифта используйте следующее

```
MainTextEdit->setFont(QFont("Courier", 9));
```

Для сохранения файлов

```
void MyClass::write(QByteArray data)
{
    QFile file("out.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out.write(data);
    file.close();
}
```